# Flex4 finding the name of the selected XML item

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, syntax, flex4

I have an XML object in Flex4 that is populating a tree (amongst other things).

I need to be able to find the name of the selected item when it is clicked in the tree.

For example:

```
<Object id="">
<Image></Image>
<Cycle></Cycle>
</Object>
<Action>
<Hide></Hide>
</Action>
```

The tags are all predefnied by me so I will know what they are, but I need to be able to know if the item a user has selected is "Object" and do something, or if they select "Action" do something else.

What is the syntax to get the names of these in flex4 and compare them?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the flash [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html)?

Comment: So are you saying the tree is populated by xml objects that can be of type Object or of type Action?  Or does each xml object contain an Object and an Action?  In either case you really don't have anything in there to derive a "name" from, other than maybe the "id" attribute.

Comment: By "name" I mean the tag name, like "Image" or "Cycle". Object and Action will each be populated by The relevent sub-nodes (they all have more attributes than shown here but they're not relevent".

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reference to the XML node, you can call the name() method:

```
var xml:XML = <data><myNode/></data>;
trace(xml.child(0).name()); //traces "myNode"
```